# Keep the linear colors of a colormap while using non-linear levels in plt.contourf

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap, color-mapping

In the following example, I would like to manually set the `levels` of a `contourf` plot to the quantiles of some variable (in order to enhance the vizualization).

But giving the `levels` also affects the scaling of the colors of the `colormap` (see how the red is extended -> the visual impression is not affected): how can I keep them linear?

In other words, how can I keep the colors of the colorbar just as in the top subplot, but corresponding to the values as in the bottom subplot?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xvec = np.linspace(-10.,10.,100)
x,y = np.meshgrid(xvec, xvec)
z = -(x**2 + y**2)**2

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(2)
p0 = ax0.contourf(x, y, z, 100)
fig.colorbar(p0, ax=ax0)
p1 = ax1.contourf(x, y, z, 100, levels=np.percentile(z, np.linspace(0,100,101)))
fig.colorbar(p1, ax=ax1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Did I miss some easy solution (I bet yes), or should I try to do some `matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap` manipulation... ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm` to specify the levels to use for the colormapping.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors 
import numpy as np

xvec = np.linspace(-10.,10.,100)
x,y = np.meshgrid(xvec, xvec)
z = -(x**2 + y**2)**2

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(2)
p0 = ax0.contourf(x, y, z, 100)
fig.colorbar(p0, ax=ax0)

levels = np.percentile(z, np.linspace(0,100,101))
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(levels,256)
p1 = ax1.contourf(x, y, z, 100, levels=levels, norm=norm)
fig.colorbar(p1, ax=ax1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I suppose the 256 is for the number of levels in any original `colormap`. Works great, thanks. I wonder... how does one become aware of such refined options? I read the doc about colormap normalization (https://matplotlib.org/users/colormapnorms.html) etc., but never came accross this `matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm`... where do we learn such things?

Comment: Yes 256 is the number of colors in colormap. If you have a colormap `cmap` you would get that number as `cmap.N`. In that article you link to there is a section [Discrete bounds](https://matplotlib.org/users/colormapnorms.html#discrete-bounds) which tells us about `BoundaryNorm`.